# How can I customize the existing patterns?

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to turn a color SVG to BW patterns but the predefined patterns included in Inkscape are to coarse for my objects. How can I make them more fine grained, e.g. the stripes finer? Furthermore I'd like to define finer horizontal stripes, etc. Note this is purely vector patterns and not raster e.g. no bitmaps involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own patterns are scaled easily, if you have visible the shape or group that you defined to be a fill pattern.

- select a filled shape
- switch to the node tool
- drag the handles which have appeared around your fill pattern shape:

[image]

Here two rectangles have same fill. The lower is selected. At the top middle you see my pattern shape and the handles which have been dragged to scale the fill bigger. It works to both directions.

Preset fill patterns cannot be scaled this way, some underhood knowledge is needed. But there's a workaround:

Select a filled shape and goto Object > Pattern > Pattern to Objects. The fill disappears and the used pattern shape appears to the top left corner of the worksheet. Move it aside, scale and define it to be your own fill pattern. It is scalable normally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am trying to customize Inkscape built in patterns to be finer. I dont have any custom patterns I am a newbie :) What I have is an SVG with colors that I'd like to replace with BW patterns i.e. Colors -> BW patterns but the built in ones are too coarse.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua you can draw anything in any size, select it, scale it smaller, if needed and define it to be your pattern. Before defining something to be a pattern, move it aside from the worksheet.